# How to transfer a purchased app from iPhone to iPad?

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, ipad

I have bought Talking Ben app on my iPhone. I also have an iPad, how can I transfer this purchase onto my iPad?

I already tried using my iTunes. But i dont know how to do it. Also both my iPad and and iPhone use the same Apple ID.

Answer (score 5):

There are (at least) two ways to accomplish that

#### via iTunes

- sync your iPhone with iTunes. This will copy Talking Ben to iTunes
- connect your iPad to the same computer
- click on the iPad name in in the sidebar and go to the the Apps section
- check the mark in front of Talking Ben
- sync the iPad -> Talking Ben gets copied to the iPad

#### directly on the iPad

- open the App Store app
- tap on Purchases (or just search for Talking Ben again)
- install

The iPad option only works if you are logged into the App Store with the same Apple ID on both devices, the iTunes option also works with different IDs.

---

As pointed out in the comment certain applications provide a specific iPad version which must be bought separately. You can still install the iPhone version in the iPad as well but will have to accept the usual restrictions concerning screen size unless the app was specifically coded to work both on iPad and iPhone.

Comment: This will only work if the App is Universal, and the same installer works for both Devices. If it isn't, he'll have to buy the iPad version, too.

Comment: You can always install the iPhone version on the iPad if you can live with the restrictions. What's an installer, btw?

Comment: You're absolutely right with the possibility of installing the iPhone version in the iPad, forgot about that. For *installer* I meant the source code and what happens *under the hood*. It's, certainly, not accurate, but shorter when posting just a comment.

Comment: To add to above correct information make sure you know you game centre information if you wish to play the same games at the point where you are as some apps/games use gamecentre